# Can I install secondary OS on a different HDD

Tags: server, hard-drive

I would like to make a fresh OS install on my server, however I would like to have the possibility to switch back to the current system with all the files and configurations in the furture if needed. The server has 6 HDDs, and only 2 of them are being used for the current system. I was wondering whether it would be possible to unmount the 2 HDDs which are in use and then use the rest to install and run new OS? I have no experience with sys administation so wanted to double check whether this is a feasible solution and whether I would be able to switch back to those 2 HDDs in the future without any consequences?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I suppose my question was mainly to double check with more experienced users whether it is acceptable to install a secondary OS on the same machine and if there are any repercussions to be aware of.

Comment: You're referring to "dual boot" configuration and it's very common ;)

Comment: Thanks for the keyword !

Comment: ALWAYS make backups of your personal files. And make an extra one before you start setting up a dual boot: you will need to shrink partitions from the current OS and that -can- destroy data if you mess up

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Perhaps you could point me to any resource that describes shrinking of parittions, so far I have only found guides that use Gparted but I am not sure whether my server can run programs with graphical user interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)